# matching regex not working properly in zsh

Tags: regex, shell, zsh

I am finding some wrong results here in bash. I dont know why can some one help to understand whats happening

```
   $ [[ example.com/something =~ .*\.mp4\?.* ]] && echo matched2
   matched2
```

My regex is `^.*\.mp4\?.*` should only match something like  `example.com/file.mp4?size=large` but how come its matching without any such pattern here.

I am using zsh

```
$ zsh --version
zsh 5.7.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, I get no output with 4.4.19. What `bash` version are you running?

Comment: Nor on bash 5.0.16.

Comment: Just a suggestion, try saving the regex in a variable so you test the variable and not the regexp directly, since I can't reproduce that issue as well.

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to do this with a regexp? `[[ $something == *.mp4[?]* ]]` should be sufficient.

Comment: @ paxdiablo I am running this on zsh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The backslashes aren't part of the regular expression; the shell performs quote removal to generate the regular expression `.*.mp4?.*`, which matches any string containing 1 or more arbitrary characters, followed by `mp` and an optional 4. You need to escape the backslashes as well.

```
[[ example.com/something =~ .*\\.mp4\\?.* ]] && echo matched2
```

This will produces the desired regular expression `.*\.mp4\?.*`.

(Note that regular expression aren't anchored to the beginning or end of the input string, so `\\.mp4\\?` or `'\.mp4\?'` would suffice.)